# What problems are about HttpAgilityPack

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1

Here what is code html on website.

```
<span class="def">

to make something 

<a class="query" title="clear" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/clear"></a>

 or 

<a class="query" title="easy" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/easy"></a>

 to 

<a class="query" title="understand" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/understand"></a>

 by 

<a class="query" title="describing" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/describe"></a>

 or giving 

<a class="query" title="information" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/information"></a>

 about it:
```

How to do that? I want get that results:**to make something or to by or giving about it**

I have code of httpAgilityPack.

```
string url = "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/appeal";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string content = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (...)
        {
           ...
        }
```

I hope everyone to help.

Comment: Thou shalt not screen scrape.

Comment: I dont understand. Can't have to get it?

Comment: Sorry, just a lame joke of mine.

Comment: Have my question are difficult???.

Comment: 2 weeks,no one and no question.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async void print_def(String uristring)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //verify uri is a valid
            Uri outuri;
            if(Uri.TryCreate(uristring,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute,out outuri))
            {
                //try to get the site
                HttpResponseMessage response=new HttpResponseMessage();
                try
                {
                    response = await client.GetAsync(outuri);
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException exc)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error geting Html from site");
                }

               //check if site returned success code 200
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    String html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("succes");
                    HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmldoc.LoadHtml(html);

                    foreach (HtmlNode defnode in htmldoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").Where(spannode => spannode.Attributes.Contains("class")&&spannode.Attributes["class"].Value.Equals("def")))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(defnode.InnerText.ToString());
                        //put here whaterver you want to do with the text
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you can just copy paste this function into your projekt and give pass the url you want to scrape as a String. Works for me hope that answers your question.